# css button is moving after adding a field in an upper list

Tags: css, dom, button

**Hello guys !**

So that's the problem : I've 3 tables which are 3 items lists. I've 2 buttons (cancel/submit) below the lists. When I add a row in one of the lists : the buttons below escapes, moving right. What the heck ?

If someone has an idea of how to fix it, it'll save me some hair : https://jsfiddle.net/sqonLbv4/

Thanks a lot

HTML

```
  <div class="cols3">
    <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
    <table id="tableField1"></table>
    <input id="field1" name="field1" type="text" />
    <button id="field1Add" name="field1Add" class="btn btnOrange" type="button" onclick="field1Add()">Add</button>
    <button id="field1Delete" name="field1Delete" class="btn btnBlack" type="button" onclick="field1Delete()">Delete last</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols3">
    <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
    <table id="tableField2"></table>
    <input id="field2" name="field2" type="text" />
    <button id="field2Add" name="field2Add" class="btn btnOrange" type="button" onclick="field2Add()">Add</button>
    <button id="field2Delete" name="field2Delete" class="btn btnBlack" type="button" onclick="field2Delete()">Delete last</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols3">
    <label for="field3">Field List 3</label>
    <table id="tableField3"></table>
    <input id="field3" name="field3" type="text" />
    <button id="field3Add" name="field3Add" class="btn btnOrange" type="button" onclick="Field3Add()">Add</button>
    <button id="field3Delete" name="field3Delete" class="btn btnBlack" type="button" onclick="field3Delete()">Delete last</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="btnsForm" class="subcontainer">
  <button id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" class="btn btnBlack" type="button">Cancel</button>
  <button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btnOrange" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var field1 = document.querySelector("#field1");

function field1Add() {
  var table = document.querySelector("#tableField1");
  var cell = table.insertRow(0).insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = field1.value;
}

function field1Delete() {
  var table = document.querySelector("#tableField1");
  table.deleteRow(0);
}

var fieldList2 = [];
var field2 = document.querySelector("#field2");

function field2Add() {
  var table = document.querySelector("#tableField2");
  var cell = table.insertRow(0).insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = field2.value;
}

function field2Delete() {
  var table = document.querySelector("#tableField2");
  table.deleteRow(0);
}

var fieldList3 = [];
var field3 = document.querySelector("#field3");

function field3Add() {
  var table = document.querySelector("#tableField3");
  var cell = table.insertRow(0).insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = field3.value;
}

function field3Delete() {
  var table = document.querySelector("#tableField3");
  table.deleteRow(0);
}
```

CSS (aka the devil)

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.subcontainer {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.cols3 {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0.3rem 3rem;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.btnCentered {
  text-align: center;
}

.btnTitle {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.btnOrange {
  background-color: chocolate;
  border-color: chocolate;
}

.btnOrange:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: #000;
}

.btnBlack {
  color: #000;
  border-color: #000;
}

.btnBlack:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: #000;
}

.btnBlack:active {
  color: #f16e00;
  border-color: #f16e00;
}

.btnsTable {
  white-space: initial;
}

#btnsForm {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `float: left` to position things next to each other in this case. In this case you'd rather want to use a flexbox. Change the css to this to have it display next to each other:

```
.cols3 {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 0 0.3rem 3rem;
}

#numbers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

edit: There are way better ways to position things on certain places nowadays. If you want to position multiple elements on either the X axis or Y axis there is what we call a `flexbox`. If you want to position multiple elements on both the X axis AND Y axis, there is a `grid`.

Comment: Yeah it's a little shitty, i surely have to improve it. Thanks a lot for your time, this problem's indeed solved !

edit : a new problem appeared though : it derails the title 'numbers'

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sqonLbv4/

Answer (score 0):

Found it !

```
.cols3 {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 0 0.3rem 3rem;
}

.subcontainer {
    display: flex;
}
```

For the HTML part, all the titles h3 have been moved **before** the div subcontainer.
With that, it's all fixed.

But like Terry said, the grid properties should have been used, it's better when you try to arrange objects on X & Y position.

Thanks